# Backbone filter through an array of arrays to match a string

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to implement the following:

I have a MongoDB Schema like so:

```
var DocumentSchema = new Schema({
  num: Number,
  authors: [String]
})
```

Which is being used for the backend for a Backbone collection. I am having trouble understanding how to filter through each document's `authors` array to match a username.

Something like:

```
var DocumentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Document,

  match_username: function() {
    var username = 'foo'
    // match username to author...
    })
  }
});
```

To summarize, I would be filtering through the `authors` array for each document in the collection to check if there is a username match. If the username matches, get `num` and store in a new array to be returned.

What is the most efficient way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like what you need is:

```
var DocumentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Document,

    match_username: function() {
        var username = 'foo'
        return this.chain().filter(function(doc) {
            return _.indexOf(doc.get('authors'), username) > -1;
        }).map(function(doc) {
            return doc.get('num');
        }).value();
    }
});
```

It's filtering using [`_.indexOf`](http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf) on the `authors`, then [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) on the `num` of the filtered collection.

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew7fu/)**

Comment: @kailey Thank you! This is really nice. I take it you use Underscore a lot. Besides the docs, can you recommend any good resources or tutorials for really learning its best parts?

Comment: @EvanEmolo That's a good question. I've mostly learned by looking at other people's source code. [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) has some good stuff. Wish I had a better answer for you. I will say, that I went through a lot of growing pains before I gained a better understanding of how to use it.